# How to set column value to zero after a month expires

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a page where users can download some content. There are two types of users - Basic and Premium.
Basic users can download only 100 contents per month. In DB I have a users table which contains `downloadCounter` column, and every time user downloads something that column value is increased by 1.
But how can I reset that value to 0 every new month? Can that be done in MySQL directly, or there is a way with Laravel and Carbon?

Comment: use cron job to reset counter and execute this command monthly on day 1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling documentation over here

Comment: Do you have any reference/tutorial for setting cron job on Amazon Instance (CentOS)? ... I'm a total beginner with cron.

Comment: okay then I will add sample case in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first create a command like this

```
php artisan make:command testcommand
```

Now, testcommand.php is created at app\Console\Commands directory.

Open that file then add $signature like this:

```
protected $signature = 'test_command';
```

You can add some desciption of command below in file.
Then you can find a function named handle() at the buttom of file. You should write all code to reset your count over there.

```
public function handle()
    {
     // write code here to reset downloadCounter
    }
```

Now open the Kernal.php file inside app\Console\ directory then add following.

```
protected $commands = [
    //
    Commands\testcommand::class,
];
```

After this, add following to Schedule function like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('test_command')->monthlyOn(1, '00:00')->timezone('Asia/Kathmandu');
    }
```

You can check whether the job working or not by simply entering command `php artisan test_command` in your local environment. For, live case you can make scheduling everyMinute() to check it's functionality.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Before I try this example, I'd like to ask you - is this going to work only on my local enviroment? What about my server? Like I've stated above, I'm using Amazon Linux Instance. Should I add something there to start the scheduler?

Comment: I'm not too much familiar about  Amazon server. But, In general It has been executed by the server no configuration should be added

Comment: If all you're doing is just run an update query, then skip the command creation part and use a closure to schedule the code directly. See the first example here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#defining-schedules